# Unable to download softwares from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit version
Whenever I try to download some software from ubuntu Software Center
it used to show “Failed to download package files” error?

So I followed this post
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

And tried all steps but after following step 5 of this post my software manager is not even allowing me to download rest softwares as well, install button is not coming in front of softwares in software center>

Please help me to get out this problem.

Result in terminal:

```
shikhar@Shikhar-asus:~$ sudo apt-get update  
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 3,435 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting       Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stabIgn   http://dl.google.com stable InRelease  
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid,   got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Comment: Are you using proxy under network?

Comment: I installed 'tor' from software center before but now even after uninstalling situation is still the same,
I have also checked network connection setting in that also proxy is selected as none.

Comment: @AgentCool that link didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I use internet provided by my institute which doesn't allow me to connect to http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ server.
Unchecking it from repositories solves the problem.
Software & Update => other sources tab => uncheck http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/.